# Dissecting a weird expression into conversions

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, implicit-conversion

I'm interested in what's going on with the expression `int*&& x = new int[10]();` regarding conversions. I'm hoping the expression is well-formed and not UB to begin with.

Based on what I've found out reading cppreference.com, mostly [Temporary materialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Temporary_materialization), my analysis would go something like this:

The expression `int[10]()` is a prvalue of type `int[10]` which gets converted to xvalue denoting the temporary object of type `int[10]`.

The expression `new int[10]()` is a prvalue of type `int*` which gets converted to xvalue denoting the temporary object of type `int*`.

However, I'm having second thoughts about this because the first conversion doesn't fit any of the mentioned criteria in [Temporary materialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Temporary_materialization). They say that one of the circumstances which causes temporary materialization is *when performing an array-to-pointer conversion (see above)...*, but since I haven't mentioned any array-to-pointer conversion (and I can't see any other possible fit besides maybe discarded-value expression which I don't understand) I'm starting to doubt. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: The whole of `new int[10]()` is a single expression see case (2) here - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new  where `int[10]` is the type and `()` the initialiser.

Comment: @RichardCritten Are you saying it's wrong to observe the part `int[10]()` as something that would involve any conversions since we use it as a new-expression ?

Comment: Exactly it's just the parameters `type` and `initialiser` to the `new` expression.  There are no objects created before `new` creates, initialised and returns the pointer to the array.  You can dive deeper into the raw allocation function that `expression new` uses see here - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new - but they just allocate raw memory and do not create objects.

Comment: @RichardCritten That make sense. Thanks